# DocuSign Tab Update Failing with No Error Message

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to update Tabs belonging to a recipient in Docusign with their REST API. I am using `PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs` to make the request, and my JSON is as follows:

```
{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"CustomLabel", "value":"Test"}]}
```

I have confirmed that this is the correct information to send (at least I think it is) to their API from the [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipientTabs/) and from the fact that everything else I try gives me an error.

I get a `null` response from the API when I submit and my values are unchanged in the template.

If there is anything I missed or something I am doing wrong I would love it if someone could give me a hand.

Update: Apparently I am getting a message back that says "The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  Tab not found in envelope."

I have verified that the Tab exists and the Label is correct so I will find out why it isn't able to be found. Still unsure why SDK gave me a null when the API returned a useful message to me.

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Yes, you should get a more useful error message. This a bug in the SDKs.

Comment: I am using their PHP SDK that I assume is up to date. Weird thing is that it checks the response and returns null if the response is blank, but I decided to dump the value of the response just to be sure and then I saw the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `tabId` in the request and your URI should be like below for updating value for a recipient in an envelope. I am seeing you are trying to update template's tab value, same `tabId` need to be added for template as well.

URI:

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "textTabs": [{
        "tabLabel": "CustomLabel",
        "value": "Test",
        "tabId": "814e8e95-68c7-4f2f-9648-8d536c5c5e4d"
    }]
}
```

Comment: where do I get this tabId from?

Comment: The tabID is returned in the response when creating a tab method. You can also get it by calling the GetDocumentTabs method (at least in the C# SDK) which I believe is the documents/[documentID]/tabs REST method.